How to show that if T is a decidable L-theory then the set of all L-statement is recursively enumerable
Consider the following theorem

Each L-theory consistent and decidable can be extended to a L-theory
which is consistent, decidable and complete.

The main idea of the proof is to build an increasing succession of consistent theories starting from T and adding step by step a L-sentence or its negation.
To make this construction possible it is required that the set of all L-statements is recursively enumerable, but I don't know how to show it starting from the hypothesis of T-decidability.
I know that if T is decidable then the set of its theorems is recursive and so recursively enumerable but what about the L-statements?

For each $n$, you can generate all of the finitely many strings over the language $L$ of length at most $n$ and using at most the first $n$ variables and first $n$ non-logical symbols, then recursively check which ones are "statements" and spit those out. This will enumerate them all as $n\to\infty$.

The decidability hypothesis is used here: "you can generate all of the finitely many strings over the language ", isn't it?
